How to have a pip editable install not install dependencies that are already installed in editable mode
I am often working on multiple python packages with interdependencies defined in pyproject.toml. I want them all installed in editable mode, which seems harder than it should be. What I want to do is to:

Clone each package locally using git
Install each package in editable mode with pip install -e . Notionally, I'd do this in logical order for dependency.

Let us say I have two packages, parent and child, where child lists parent as a dependency in pyproject.toml. If I install parent then child in editable mode then when installing child, pip will try to download and re-install parent from the repository. This can cause confusion if not realized, since you might not realize you've accidently installed a non-editable version of parent into your environment.
Is there any way to tell pip to respect the version of the package you already have installed in editable mode? I would like a way to do this in pyproject.toml, or by providing some flag to pip.
Options Already Considered
I know I could use pip --no-deps with child, but that causes it to not install any dependencies. Sometimes child has dependencies that you'll want installed in addition to parent.
I could also always install in reverse order (child then parent), which isn't a bad solution. But this can get complicated if you are working on multiple "children", or have more complex dependency trees.

What build backend are you using for your packages? There are probably some options if you're using something like pdm or poetry, but I'm not sure how I would do this with, say, setuptools. EDIT: Actually, not just build backend, but are you using any kind of project management?

Just using setup tools. Currently not doing any project management other than using pip with pyproject.toml. I'd be willing to look into project management tools if they'd be a better solution. I have heard of poetry, but never looked into why I'd use it over just pip. My needs have been pretty simple before now.

With poetry or pdm (or I assume hatch or similar projects), you'd be able to add dependencies by URL/path into to a separate group from the main dependencies. So basically, I think you could add parent to the main project.dependencies list and also a separate dev.dependencies list. Then you could install your child package with the appropriate group so that the parent was pulled from the right place, while not "polluting" the dependencies for anyone who installs the final versions of the packages (say, from PyPI).

I see, I'll take a look at poetry and pdm.

If it's helpful, I can write up an answer using pdm. It wouldn't actually answer the question though, which is why I left that as a comment :-)

@darthbith Its fine to leave it as a comment I think, because you are right, it doesn't answer the question.
For context: my team members are scientists and engineers first, and developers second.  Every new tool, process, etc that they need to learn makes it more difficult to get adoption. They are using pip already, so I was hoping that I could do the work and setup the pyproject.toml to make this just work, without asking people to learn yet another tool.

I get that, I'm a reformed scientist myself :-) You may want to look at uv from Astral, it will probably replace a lot of these functions in pdm/poetry/hatch and is like 100x faster to boot. A tool worth learning if there ever was one, and if people know pip there's the uv pip subcommand which is a drop-in replacement for pip

"Reformed scientist". Nice term! I'll take a look at uv, looks interesting....
